# WebappClassLoader unable to load a resource

Tags: classloader, dicom, dcm4che

I have the following code that tries to read a Dicom image:

```
public  BufferedImage readDicomFile(File dicomFile) {

    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM").next();
    BufferedImage tempImage = null;
    try {
        if (!dicomFile.exists()) {          
            return null;
        }
        ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
        tempImage = ImageIO.read(dicomFile);            
        DicomObject obj = new DicomInputStream(dicomFile).readDicomObject();
        String overlayData = obj.getString(1610625024);
        if ((overlayData != null) && (overlayData.length() > 0)) {
            tempImage = combineImages(tempImage,
                    OverlayUtils.extractOverlay(obj, 1610625024, reader,
                            "FFFFFF"));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tempImage;
}
```

However, this is what I am getting:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.dcm4che.data.DcmParserFactory], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at org.dcm4cheri.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReaderSpi.canDecodeInput(DcmImageReaderSpi.java:113)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$CanDecodeInputFilter.filter(ImageIO.java:567)
at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:810)
at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:508)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.java:646)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at edu.kfshrc.dm.services.DicomViewerService.readDicomFile(DicomViewerService.java:565)
at edu.kfshrc.dm.services.DicomViewerService.extractImageFromDicom(DicomViewerService.java:414)
at edu.kfshrc.dm.servlet.DicomViewerServlet.doGet(DicomViewerServlet.java:131)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
SEVERE:     at org.dcm4cheri.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReaderSpi.canDecodeInput(DcmImageReaderSpi.java:113)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.ImageIO$CanDecodeInputFilter.filter(ImageIO.java:567)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:810)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:508)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.java:646)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
SEVERE:     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
SEVERE:     at edu.kfshrc.dm.services.DicomViewerService.readDicomFile(DicomViewerService.java:565)
SEVERE:     at edu.kfshrc.dm.services.DicomViewerService.extractImageFromDicom(DicomViewerService.java:414)
SEVERE:     at edu.kfshrc.dm.servlet.DicomViewerServlet.doGet(DicomViewerServlet.java:131)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am passing a File object that points to a certain path: "c:\temp2\testing.dcm". When it come to the line that tries to read the Dicom file, it gives the above error.

Could you please help?

Comment: I used "ImageIO.scanForPlugins()" and it worked. However, it wasn't working correctly all the time. It was sporadic. Also, the reading of the image using "ImageIO.read(dicomFile)" was sporadic also. Sometimes, the reading succeeds and sometimes it gives a "NullPointerException" or "Can't obtain format". Sometimes, it doesn't give an error, but reads wrongly, resulting in an image that can't be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam Wael ,

The root cause for the problem is the Servlet container (tomcat,..) cannot handle registering/de-registering  native libraries automatically

this means when dcm4che loads ImageIO DICOM plugin which uses native library inside it owns the plugin , if u want to use it from another webApp (Servlet) you have to scan the plugin again for every execution of dcm4che DICOM reader/writer code .

i recommend to de-register the native ImageIO Plugins by yourself after each excution to prevent potential memory leaks in the future

```
     try{
ImageIO.scanForPlugins()
    //Dicom code
        }
    catch {
    //exceptions
    }
    finally {
                try {
                    // De-register any locally registered IIO plugins. Relies on
                    // each web app having its own context class loader.
                    final IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
                    final LocalFilter localFilter = new LocalFilter(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); 

                    // scanForPlugins uses context  class loader
                    Iterator<Class<?>> categories = registry.getCategories();

                    while (categories.hasNext()) {
                        Class<?> category = categories.next();
                        Iterator<?> providers = registry.getServiceProviders(category, localFilter, false);

                        // Copy the providers, as de-registering while iterating
                        // over providers will lead to
                        // ConcurrentModificationExceptions.
                        List<Object> providersCopy = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        while (providers.hasNext()) {
                            providersCopy.add(providers.next());
                        }

                        for (Object provider : providersCopy) {
                            registry.deregisterServiceProvider(provider);
                            log.debug(String.format("Unregistered locally installed provider class: %s",provider.getClass()));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    _logger.error("Exception occured while de-registering locally registered IIO plugins", ex);
                }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks a lot. It actually worked. Just one little thing I am facing after that. When I do some changes on the code and compile, it gives an error when it comes to converting to JPEG image. This is the error: SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't obtain format
This error goes away when I restart the my application server, which is glassfish, and then it works fine. Do you any idea why this is happening, and how can I eliminate the need to restart the server?

Comment: Salam Wael
this cloud happen for multiple reasons , its hard to know without seeing the code , also keep in mind that ImageIO plugin  for jpeg readers and writers uses nativeLib as implementation for compression algorithm 
i recommend to 
-have ImageIo jar files + native dll in the global glass-fish library directory not in web application WEB-INF\lib 
-cleanup used plugins after each request
-scan for plugin before getting the readers and waiters every time

this can help you in general , without code investigation

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Ahmed. It worked when I moved all jar files that were under the WEB-INF\lib folder to the C:\opt\glassfish3\glassfish\lib folder. I tried to do changes a lot of times and it is working fine without having to restart the server.